# How do I reference the WPF Toolkit in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, ironpython, wpftoolkit

I'm trying to use the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) with my Visual 2010 project (I'm interested in the chart controls found in the `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization` namespace), but cannot figure out which assembly to reference.

I've installed the toolkit and it seems to have installed into `C:\Program Files (x86)\WPF Toolkit\v3.5.50211.1`. I've read some posts about how I might need to copy the assemblies to the GAC but I attempted this and the following code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("WPFToolkit")
```

still fails.

Has anyone used WPF Toolkit lately with VS2010? How did you add a reference to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import sys, clr
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\WPF Toolkit\v3.5.50211.1')
clr.AddReference("WPFToolkit")
```

You may also need to be running the .NET 2 version of IronPython 2.6, since the WPFToolkit site doesn't say if it's compatible with .NET 4.

Comment: That works, and so does `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath()`, but because having the path hard coded in is highly environment dependent and inflexible, I decided to just copy the WPFToolkit assemblies to my project's folder and then a bare `clr.AddReference("WPFToolkit")` works. Now I'm having a different, designer related issue though; [see here](http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/379).

Comment: @Aphex: See Scrappydog's answer for how to solve the "path hard coded" issue.  Make a well-known external binaries/assemblies folder, relative to your well-known source folder for your project, then refer to the assembly with a relative path.  I've seen this solution work in multiple companies/teams.

Answer (score 2):

In the path where you installed WPF toolkit (i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\WPF Toolkit\v3.5.50211.1) you will find multiple DLL files. Those are all you need.

In your WPF project in visual studio, do "add reference" and then in the "browse" tab select those DLLs and add them.

I suggest you copy-paste them from the installation folder into your application project folder before referencing them, like that you can add them to your source control system and you will be sure that the toolkit follows your application from computer to computer.

Answer (score 2):

use following http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog for installation and refer
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading the WPF Toolkit binaries and adding them to your solution directly.

(vs. installing the WPF Toolkit MSI and then referencing them where ever it is they were installed to...)

One advantage for this approach is that you can easily check them into your source control system vs. being dependent on the WPF Toolkit install being run...