# WPFToolkit does not show up in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I'm new to WPF and its toolkit and interested in using it and have found following URLs:

[How do I reference the WPF Toolkit in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779227/how-do-i-reference-the-wpf-toolkit-in-visual-studio-2010)

[WPF Toolkit - Verify upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582626/wpf-toolkit-verify-upgrade)

However, I'm not sure about the solution. I tried to add its DLL from Solution Explorer by adding its DLL under References. Yes, I do not see any WPFToolkit on Toolbox. I'm not sure why they mean by adding those lines to GAC. Any idea?

It has been installed and it is the latest version. Can somebody give me a direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the **Browse** button in the toolbox? You should be able to find the *WpfToolkit.DLL* in the folder *C:/Program Files (x86)/WPF Toolkit/v3.5.50211.1* or similar.

Comment: Yes, I choose what  I need from the directory/list of item then click Open. It ends up with nothing. I mean nothing happens.

Comment: OK? No `WPFToolkit` under the `References` tab? What version of .NET Framework is your project?

Comment: Yes. that has been there already and I'm using .NET 4.0